# Python: pygame - not importing image

Tags: python, image, pygame, pycharm

I am using Python 3.4.2 on Pycharm. the image I want to display is in the same folder as the code file. Everything seems to run fine untilI try to import a picture. Here is my code:

```
import pygame
import sys
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()


white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
red = (255,0,0)
green = (0,255,0)
blue = (0,0,255)
yellow = (255,255,0)
cyan = (0,255,255)
purple = (255,0,255)

setDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((400,300))
pygame.display.set_caption("this is a game")
singlePixel = pygame.PixelArray(setDisplay)
setDisplay.fill(green)
image = pygame.image.load("Jeffery.png")
while True:
    pygame.display.update()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        setDisplay.blit(image,0,0)

        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
```

Whenever I try to run the program, I get the following error:

```
"TypeError: invalid destination position for blit"
```

Please help! I have researched this for over an hour and I still cannot find a solution! All help is much appreciated!

Comment: THe bilt expects a tuple as a parameter, thats the mistake

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that your blit statement is in the for loop. For Pyhton 2.x or 3.x, the error is the same. By "invalid destination position for blit", it means that you can't put that statement in that place. Most people I see, using either versions of Python, will put the blit statement ***right after*** the for loop, but not in it. Make sure it is still in your while loop, and the error should be gone. Also, instead of:

```
(image, 0, 0)
```

Do:

```
(image, (0, 0))
```

to prevent another error on invalid stuff in the (). I hope this helps you!

Comment: i appreciate the help. I have corrected those mistakes, but now i get an error that says: "pygame.error: Surfaces must not be locked during blit" is there a way to fix this? thanks in advance!

Comment: nevermind. i got it to work, i just had to delete the pixelArray line. Thanks so much for helping!!

Comment: The pixelArray line might have locked up the Surface. You need the Surface to be unlocked to be able to blit things onto it